# How to count images in summernote div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, summernote

I have summernote div and I want to count inserted images on that editable summernote div. I'm using [`onChange`](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#onchange) callback and JQuery's `find()` method. But `console.log` returns **0** when I have more than 0 image.

Here is my script.

**HTML**

```
<div id="summernote"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
            placeholder: 'Hello bootstrap 4',
            tabsize: 2,
            height: 400,
            callbacks: {
                onChange: function(e) {
                    var imageCount = $("#summernote").find('img').length;
                    console.log("img count:" + imageCount);
                }
            }
});
```

How can I count images when user change something in `<div id='summernote'>`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[summernote.change](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#onchange) event has one argument: **contents**. This argument contains the html source in your summernote. You may get the same html with [get--set-code](https://summernote.org/getting-started/#get--set-code):

```
var markupStr = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
```

Therefore, you need to change from:

```
var imageCount = $("#summernote").find('img').length;
```

to:

```
var imageCount = $(contents).find('img').length;
```

The snippet:

```js
$('#summernote').summernote({
  placeholder: 'Hello bootstrap 4',
  tabsize: 2,
  height: 400,
  callbacks: {
      onChange: function(contents) {
          var imageCount = $(contents).find('img').length;
          console.log("img count:" + imageCount);
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<!-- include summernote css/js-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.8/summernote.min.js"></script>


<div id="summernote"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your version of summernote doesn't support the jquery custom event styles. So you can try this:

```
$('#summernote').on('summernote.change', function(we, contents, $editable) {
    var count = $(contents).find('img').length;  
    console.log('images number : ' + count);
});
```

Referenz: https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#oninit